# Load nested routes in same router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an **Angular 4** application and my `private.component.html` something like this:

```
<app-breadcrumb></app-breadcrumb>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

And my routing:

```
const privateRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: PrivateComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'dashboard',
                component: DashboardComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'settings',
                component: SettingsComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'companies',
                component: CompaniesComponent,
                children: [
                    {
                        path: 'add',
                        component: FormCompanyComponent
                    },
                    {
                        path: ':id',
                        component: CompanyComponent
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

All components on first level is rendered in **router-outlet** of `PrivateComponent`. But I want (if possible) all other child (and I can have multiple levels), like `/companies/add` or `/companies/20` still rendered in the same **router-outlet** of my private template. My actual code, sure, expect I have the outlet inside the `companies.component.html`.

This is important to implement my *breadcrumb* component and write *"Home > Companies > Apple Inc."*, for example.

It's possible create some structure like that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Adding to @Karsten's answer, basically what you want is to have a componentless route and the empty path as the default component such as this:

```
const privateRoutes: Routes = [
    path: 'companies',
    data: {
        breadcrumb: 'Companies'
    }
    children: [{
            path: '', //url: .../companies
            component: CompaniesComponent,
        } {
            path: 'add', //url: .../companies/add
            component: FormCompanyComponent,
            data: {
                breadcrumb: 'Add Company' //This will be "Companies > Add Company"
            }
        }, {
            path: ':id', //url: .../companies/5
            component: CompanyComponent
            data: {
                breadcrumb: 'Company Details' //This will be "Companies > Company Details"
            }
        }
    ]
];
```

You will need to modify the breadcrumb dynamically to change "Company Details" with the actual company name.

Answer (score 5):

The `/companies/add` or `/companies/20` routes would still be rendered inside the first router-outlet if you would make `companies` a componentless route.
This means you would have to leave out the component definition for that route, it would look like this:

```
        //...
        {
            path: 'companies',
            children: [
                {
                    path: 'add',
                    component: FormCompanyComponent
                },
                {
                    path: ':id',
                    component: CompanyComponent
                }
            ]
        }
```

**Update**

```
        {
            path: 'companies',
            component: CompaniesComponent
        },
        {
             path: 'companies/add',
             component: FormCompanyComponent
        },
        {
            path: 'companies/:id',
            component: CompanyComponent
        }
```

But this a little nasty in my opinion

Comment: But inside `/companies` I have a list, and when select one it's possible to view details. Where I need to put my `CompaniesComponent` now? And how about if I have 3 levels like `/companies/20/employees`?

Comment: If the components are completely separate and don't really belong inside the 'companies' scope you could work around your problem by doing something like this (see Original Comment Update)