# Render the children route in parent router-outlet

Tags: angular

My router-outlet is located in FullLayoutComponent, and my navigation menu routes are located in that template.

The first children array you see below are navigation menu routes. The children array in 'apartments' are some routes from different template located in ApartmentsComponent.

I am getting the error:

> Cannot find primary outlet to load 'ApartmentItemsComponent'

I have tried moving the apartment-items outside of the children, but then my route is wrong.

It is Home > Apartment Items, and it should be Home > Apartments > Apartment Items

```
path: '',
component: FullLayoutComponent,
data: {
  title: 'Home'
},
children: [
  {
    path: 'apartments',
    component: ApartmentsComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Apartments'
    },
    children: [
        {
         path: 'apartment-items',
         component: ApartmentItemsComponent,
         data: {
           title: 'Apartment Item'
          }
        }]
  },.....
```

How can I make apartment-items recognise my main router-outlet?

EDIT: To explain it more on what I want to achieve.

[image]

So basically, when I press view more, I would like to render Apartment Items component in that main router outlet.

So my route would look like Home / Apartments / Apartment Item.

If I remove Apartment Items from children, my route will look like Home / Apartment Item. But if I leave it in children then I get that error I posted above.

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: Got any answer?

Comment: @AliSajid Unfortunately no

Comment: How did you solved it?

Comment: and why dont you use ng-content here?

Comment: I solved the problem with the Doug's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41851898/using-child-routing-in-the-same-router-outlet-as-parents)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve, but your current Router configuration expects a `<router-outlet>` tag within the template of the `ApartmentsOutlet` component because your are nesting the components: The FullLayoutComponent already has a , which is where the ApartmentsComponent is placed. Now it expects to find the same there to place the ApartmentItemsComponent.

**UPDATE**: I guess you want to show a list of apartments and, when users click on an apartment, to show the details of that one. A way to do that is the following:

```
const ROUTES=[

    { path: '', redirectTo: '/apartments', pathMatch: 'full' },
    {
        path: '', component: FullLayoutComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'apartments',
                children: [
                    {
                        path: '',
                        component: ApartmentListComponent,
                        canActivate: [HasClinics]
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'new',
                        component: ApartmentComponent,
                        canActivate: [HasClinics]
                    },
                    {
                        path: ':id',
                        component: ApartmentDetailsComponent
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                path: 'hotels', //just an example
                children: [ ...] //other elements
            }
        ]
    }
```

So you have a "headless" route named `apartments`. If you add nothing else, then the child with the empty path will be shown. If you add an id, something like `apartments/34`, then the details of apartment with id 34 should be given. The path `apartments/new` should show a form to add a new one

Comment: I am trying to display apartment-items in my <router-outlet> which is in FullLayoutComponent. Any hints on what should I try then?

Comment: Please update your question to explain what you are trying to do. What should `apartments` and `apartments/apartment-items` show? Are these the routes you want?

Comment: I have added an image, hope you can understand it better now.